# .gitattributes: override settings for a single file

Tags: git, gitattributes

I have a directory of .txt files that I would like to treat as binary files. This prevents git from changing the line endings of those files so the checksum is consistent on all systems.

However, I have one .txt file that I would like to keep as text. If I create a .gitattributes file like:

```
*.txt binary
foo.txt text
```

foo.txt is still treated as binary and `git diff` doesn't display changes properly. It seems like negation isn't supported in .gitattributes like it is in .gitignore. Is there any other way to make this work?

Answer (score 3):

`binary` is what [the gitattributes documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitattributes) refers to as a *macro attribute:*

> Setting the "binary" attribute also unsets the "text" and "diff" attributes as above.

So `binary` literally means `-text -diff`.  You then override the `-text` setting for `foo.txt` with the second line, but you have not overridden the `-diff` setting.  Changing the second line to:

```
foo.txt text !diff
```

would restore the default unset-ness for `diff`, while:

```
foo.txt text diff
```

will force `diff` to be set (both will presumably result in a diff, since Git has presumably not previously been detecting `foo.txt` as binary).

(Note that there's no direct way to "undo" a macro attribute other than piecemeal.  You could define your own macro attribute that undoes each piece of some existing macro attribute, e.g., define one that means `!text !diff`, which will then take away `binary`.)